# Is it possible to programmatically change email preview in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I would like to programmatically change email preview in Outlook? I am particularly interested in adding  custom icon to the right of the email header in preview pane where the attachment icon and replied to icon are as shown below.

[image: subject header icons in preview pane]

Comment: Have you looked through the outlook add-in SDK docs? That's where I would start

Comment: "Programmatically" can mean a lot of things. From writing a add-in, over intercepting the screen output and doing stuff on it, all the way to writing your own mail client.

Comment: @Christopher no it doesnt mean a lot of things in this context because the only way you can customize interface of an Office application is through VSTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that area is not open for customization.